# Properties html tags rails 4

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, ruby-on-rails-4

In pure html is as follows:

```
<input class='form-control' data-rule-minlength='2' data-rule-required='true' id='validation_name' name='validation_name' placeholder='Name' type='text'>
```

I have error in the following line of code:

```
<%= f.text_field :name, :data-rule-minlength=>'2', :data-rule-required=>'true' %>
```

someone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the hyphens you need to use string keys:

```
<%= f.text_field :name, "data-rule-minlength" => '2', "data-rule-required" => 'true' %>
```

You can also nest these under a `:data` key:

```
<%= f.text_field :name,
                 :data => {"rule-minlength" => '2', "rule-required" => 'true'} %>
```

Also, when using the nested `:data` hash, you can use underscores and it will convert to dashes in the output:

```
<%= f.text_field :name,
                 :data => {:rule_minlength => '2', :rule_required => 'true'} %>
```

Comment: Hello, I need to make the following statement to code rails 4.1 **`<a class='btn btn-contrast btn-lg fadeInRight animated' href='http://limanueva.cl/item/acd-website-html-template/5689597?ref=imagestudio'>`**   please help